# pandas: convert multiple categories to dummies

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table where each row can belong to multiple categories such as,

```
test = pd.DataFrame({
            'name': ['a', 'b'],
            'category': [['cat1', 'cat2'],['cat1', 'cat3']]
    })
```

How can I convert each category to a dummy variable in such a way that the above table becomes,

```
test_res = pd.DataFrame({
        'name': ['a', 'b'],
        'cat1': [1, 1],
        'cat2': [1, 0],
        'cat3': [0, 1]
    })
```

I tried `pd.get_dummies(test['category'])` but get the following error,

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html), but first convert `list` column to new `DataFrame`:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(test.category.values.tolist()))
      0     1
0  cat1  cat2
1  cat1  cat3

print (pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(test.category.values.tolist()), prefix_sep='', prefix=''))
   cat1  cat2  cat3
0     1     1     0
1     1     0     1
```

Last add column `name` by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
print (pd.concat([pd.get_dummies(pd.DataFrame(test.category.values.tolist()),
                                 prefix_sep='', prefix='' ), 
        test[['name']]], axis=1))
   cat1  cat2  cat3 name
0     1     1     0    a
1     1     0     1    b
```

Another solution with [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html):

```
print (test.category.astype(str).str.strip('[]'))
0    'cat1', 'cat2'
1    'cat1', 'cat3'
Name: category, dtype: object

df = test.category.astype(str).str.strip('[]').str.get_dummies(', ')
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip("'")
print (df)
   cat1  cat2  cat3
0     1     1     0
1     1     0     1

print (pd.concat([df, test[['name']]], axis=1))
   cat1  cat2  cat3 name
0     1     1     0    a
1     1     0     1    b
```

Answer (score 0):

With string categories, you can also combine the `str.get_dummies` that [jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40213278/11286509) suggested with `str.join` to save a little more code:

```py
test.category.str.join('|').str.get_dummies()
```

`str.get_dummies` uses `|` as the default separator, hence its use with `str.join`.